# Unity garbage collector taking huge amount of CPU

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, render

Hi im making a mobile game that runs well on pc, but when i try to play it on android it has some lagging problems

I checked the profiler and i noticed that the garbage collector takes too much CPU is there any method to reduce the garbage collector usage?uhuhuh

**Profiler:**
[image: Profiler screen shot]

Comment: Dont make so much garbage. It sounds like a snarky answer. But tbh its the truth the less garbage you have the leas time it will take

Comment: Without any further information @BugFinder has already told you everything we can say ^^ Use the deep profile and check which method exactly produces a lot of allocations => that's probably where you could start improving

Comment: No. Its called garbage. The garbage collector recycles garbage. Your code is likely generating too much garbage.  As i said it moght sound like a snarky answer. So being all humpfy isnt fair. It is an honest answer, hence even derhugos comment

Answer (score 1):

In short terms, [Garbage collectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)) is a mechanic, used in some languages (like C# and Java), for memory management. When a space in your memory isn't used (like an integer), the data will be "deleted" making the memory space free to use for another time.

Usually, this manifests when you declare a variable in your code and lose access to it. Here is an example:

```
public class Person
{
    private float age = 20;

    Person() {
        IncrementAge();
    }

    public void IncrementAge() {
        float newAge; // New local variable
        newAge = age + 1;
        age = newAge;
    } // Since we escape the scopes {}, we no longer have access to the "newAge" variable, the C# language will then delete the value "21" from the memory.
}
```

The variable `age` will never be deleted as long as the class Person exists, so the garbage collector will never touch this variable. On the other hand, the `newAge` variable is created and it's access is lost, so to prevent [memory leaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak) the garbage collector free the memory that is no longer used.

Basically, you want to avoid declaring new objects/variables in smaller scopes as much as you can (but it's not always possible).

I don't know your project and how it's been made but a good fix against the garbage collector is the use of [Object Pooling](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/introduction-to-object-pooling#5ff8d015edbc2a002063971d). If you instantiate everything at the start and almost nothing at **Runtime**, then obviously you will gain a lot in performances.

Hopefully this helps.